# Do I need a backend engineer for my studio right now?

Tags: server, mobile

I am working on a mobile game that requires a well thought-out backend, because it spans across the healthcare/data science space and we need to be compliant in terms of security/regulations in how we approach this. Think something like Fitbit.

My team is nearly finished with the client-side game aspect; but I am wondering whether I need to take on a short-term contract/part-time backend engineer to create our entire backend infrastructure OR someone who would work on this full-time with our team.

Here is what we would need to do:

- Setup our entire backend infrastructure and plug this into Unity
- This would require knowing how to handle (transmit/receive) data securely, and also perform computation with that data in the cloud
- Set-up an API where other developers can query our data
- Set-up our dev ops infrastructure (Docker, Jenkins) for the future

The kicker here is that we are not yet live and are just in a testing phase. I don't want this to be 2-3 weeks of work, with no users for 3 more months while we're working on other aspects of the project, with the dude having nothing to do.

Does this sound like a lot of work? Or could it easily take up a devs time for a month or two? Would a short contract be advisable here, or would it be better to hire someone FT and have them grow with us.

Comment: I don't think we can answer this question. We don't know how complex your project is and we don't know anything about the qualifications of your team. And if the know-how gap of your team is regarding what you need to do in order to comply with data protection regulations, then the person you need to hire is a lawyer, not a developer.

Comment: Oh, and remember [Brooks's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%27s_law): adding people to a late project makes it even later. You might be more successful with training your team to do all this themselves than with getting in an outsider who knows absolutely nothing about your project and needs everything explained before they can work efficiently.